# php include images randomly, echo and seperate by commas?

Tags: php, include

i want to include files, and if exist echo the filename with extension like 1.jpg, but it need to be randomly and seperated by commas like these

> ('1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg')

, but if some of pictures dont exist in specified follder, need to echo manually, example if there are only three images on folder, need to be like this

> ( 1.jpg,'2.jpg','3.jpg','default.jpg')

, Hope someone understand what im asking for.

Comment: Include files from where? Can you share what you've tried that didn't work?

Comment: from a folder $dir = 'images/bg/';

Comment: I don't understand. Where do 1,2,3 come from?

Comment: Show a 'real' example of what is in the folder and what you want to see for 'various 'lists' against that folder. Explain why the 'file names' of '1.jpg'?

Comment: i dont have example, but i can explain, i need to put all images from folder, and to randomize files, seperated by commas, and if no image exist in that folder, echo this 1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg

Comment: Ok i will try, check it
$dir 'images/bg'

echo all files in a folder, in random mode, 
if nothing found, 
echo '1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg'
Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$images = glob('/images/*.{jpeg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);

shuffle($images);

$out = '(';

foreach($images as $img)
{
    $out .= '"';
    $out .= file_exists($img) ? $img : 'default.jpg';
    $out .= '",';
}

$out .= ')';

echo $out;

?>
```

Comment: This wont work, because i want to put all images that are in follder not just 4, and need to put in randomize. Thank you

Comment: Made some edits, try it now.

Comment: bro this is not what im looking to. check this out and hope you understand me, and thank you verymuch anyway:

$dir 'images/bg' 
echo all files that are in folder in random mode, 
if nothing found, echo '1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg' 
Done.

Comment: Hey bro this almost works, but just need to show me a message if nothing exist on folder. Thank You

Comment: Check if the array is empty, `if(empty($images)) echo 'Folder is empty';`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// set minimum number of images to show

$show_min=4;

// define manual images
$manual[]="1.jpg";
$manual[]="2.jpg";
$manual[]="3.jpg";
$manual[]="4.jpg";

// shuffle images
$images_found = glob("images/bg/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE)
shuffle($images_found);


$result = '(';
foreach($images_found as $image)
{
   $result.='"' . $image . '",';
}


if (count(images_found) < $show_min)
{
    for($i=0;$i<($show_min-count(images_found));$i++)
        $result.='"' . $manual[$i] . '",';
}

$result .= ')';

//fix for last comma
$result=str_replace(",)", ")", $result);

echo $result;

?>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I have added $show_min to more flex.